# Https Request skipped in dispatchqueue.main.async called from IBAction

Tags: json, swift, https, alamofire

The request to get json and decode is skipped when called from an IBAction! But it works if it is made in viewDidLoad. Can anyone enlighten me and help me how I can solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

```
class LoginViewController:UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var login_id_field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var login_pw_field: UITextField!


    var loginData = [LoginData]()
    var storeData = [StoreData]()
    So below part in viewDidLoad() is working fine,

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    let param2 = ["login": self.login_id_field.text!]
    let url2 = "http://dev.purejoin.com/PJPI/login.php"
    print("HI")
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
        AF.request(url2, method: .post, parameters: param2, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseString { response in
            #if DEBUG
            let request = response.request
            NSLog("Request: \(request!.httpMethod!) - \(request!.url!.absoluteString)\n\(request!.httpBody.map { body in String(data: body, encoding: .utf8) ?? "" } ?? "")")
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("Response with content \(value)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Response with error: \(error as NSError): \(response.data ?? Data())")
            }
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

But here below is not working. `Dispatchqueue.main.async` is just getting skipped? At least that's what it seems like.

```
@IBAction func login_button(_ sender: Any) {
    //Check for email field that is too short or just didn't get any input
    if (self.login_id_field.text!.count < 7 ) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Email", message: "Please Check Your Email", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(ok)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    //query
    else {
        let param2 = ["login": self.login_id_field.text!]
        let url2 = "http://dev.purejoin.com/PJPI/login.php"
        print("HI")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                "Accept": "text/html",
                "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ]
            AF.request(url2, method: .post, parameters: param2, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseString { response in                        #if DEBUG
            let request = response.request
            NSLog("Request: \(request!.httpMethod!) - \(request!.url!.absoluteString)\n\(request!.httpBody.map { body in String(data: body, encoding: .utf8) ?? "" } ?? "")")
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("Response with content \(value)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Response with error: \(error as NSError): \(response.data ?? Data())")
            }
            #endif
            }
        }
        
        
        
        //MD5
        let md5 = MD5(self.login_pw_field.text!)
        print (self.loginData)
        if (md5 == String(self.loginData[0].user_password)) {
            //OPEN SEGUE
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "selectStore") as! SelectStoreViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong Password", message: "Please Check Your Password", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let ok = UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(ok)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all: never run any network requests on `DispatchQueue.main`; having it directly inside viewDidLoad, or any IBAction is also a very bad design. But also you can put breakpoints in few places (e.g. inside DispatchQueue and see if it is getting there or not

Comment: where do you suggest i put dispatchqueue.main, then?

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous calls like `DispatchQueue.main.async` enqueue work on the queue and then continue execution, there's no waiting for completion. There are various ways to work around this but thankfully you don't need any of them: your call to `DispatchQueue.main.async` is unnecessary.

Instead, just make your network request and Alamofire will call back to the main queue (by default) to execute the content of your response handler (in this case, `responseString`). From the looks of it, you need to move the logic you after after the network call into your response handler, as it depends on the result of the network call.